# Build fails when adding dialogflow dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, dialogflow-es

When I add

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.92.0-alpha'
```

to my java/android project build fails with the message that duplicate classes were found:

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AnnotationsProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProviderOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirementOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRuleOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthorizationConfig found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthorizationConfig$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthorizationConfig$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthorizationConfigOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthorizationConfigProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Backend found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Backend$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Backend$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendRule found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendRule$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendRule$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BackendRuleOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing$BillingDestination found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing$BillingDestination$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing$BillingDestinationOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Billing$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BillingOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.BillingProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ChangeType found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ChangeType$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConfigChange found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConfigChange$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConfigChange$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConfigChangeOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConfigChangeProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ConsumerProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Context found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Context$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Context$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextRule found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextRule$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextRule$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ContextRuleOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Control found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Control$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Control$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ControlOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ControlProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.CustomHttpPattern found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.CustomHttpPattern$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.CustomHttpPattern$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.CustomHttpPatternOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Explicit found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Explicit$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$ExplicitOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Exponential found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Exponential$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$ExponentialOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Linear found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$Linear$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$LinearOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptions$OptionsCase found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$BucketOptionsOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$Range found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$Range$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Distribution$RangeOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DistributionOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DistributionProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Documentation found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Documentation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Documentation$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationRule found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationRule$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationRule$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.DocumentationRuleOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Endpoint found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Endpoint$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Endpoint$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.EndpointOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.EndpointProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Experimental found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Experimental$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Experimental$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ExperimentalOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.ExperimentalProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Http found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Http$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Http$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.11.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.11.0)
```

I am not goingtoinclude the whole stacktrace because it is too long to fit in this post(it's about 65000 chars, it is the same like eabove in every line until the end of the stacktrace).
Most of the conflicting classes seem to be firebase classes.
**When i remove te dialogflow dependency, my project builds as normal.
These are all my dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-release')
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.47.0-alpha'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.AppIntro:AppIntro:v5.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-beta01'
}
```

I don't know what this is caused by.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: First remove the line implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.92.0-alpha' and check and post the error details.

Comment: @Sambit i forgot. the error disappears when I remove the dialogflow dependency. But I need it

Comment: While adding dependencies in gradle, make sure you have to latest and you should not add duplicate dependencies with different version.

Comment: you are trying to include 2 versions of dialogflow dependency, `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.92.0-alpha'` and `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.47.0-alpha'`. remove the latter one and build your project

Comment: @JudgedPluto No, there is only one dialogflow dependency included in the build.gradle files as you can see in the post.

Comment: @Sambit i now updated all my dependencies to the latest version, but it still does not work.

Comment: Have the same Problem. Any solution yet?

Comment: @Panther i haven't found a solution. Yet the only option is to work without dialogflow's dependency. As soon as I know the solution I will post an answer

Comment: @laim2003 I think I have found a solution now. At least it lets me build it:
implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.93.0-alpha'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.api.grpc'
        exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'
    }

I think you only need the first exclude line. For me both groups had duplicate classes.

Comment: @Panther Yes, that makes sense! I guess I tried it already, but I forgot. I don't know if it worked, but it worked when i had problems with other libraries that caused the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves the build problem for me:

```
implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.93.0-alpha'){
     exclude group: 'com.google.api.grpc'
     exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'
}
```

I think you may only need the first exclude line, but for me both groups have duplicated classes.